# extension of sequential probability ratio tests to particle filters?

Tags: particle-filter, sequential-analysis

I've been wondering if there are extensions of the sequential probability ratio test to account for particle filters. I ask because, in my research, I'm working with distributions that cannot be represented in closed form, hence the use of particle filters.

Does anyone have some insights on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know much about sequential testing. You might get a better answer if you gave a simple example that demonstrates the basic ideas. I can tell you, though, that if you want to take into account the uncertainty of your sample-based estimates, the central limit theorems for particle filters are valid under fairly mild regularity conditions. What you end up with ais a recursive (in time) formula for the asymptotic variances. You could get a p value or something using that.

Comment: Links to the paper that discusses this?

Comment: @Glassjawed [this friendly tutorial](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/doucet_johansen_tutorialPF2011.pdf) has a couple stated ones (bottom of page 18). [This textbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387402642) has some nice introduction to the theory (e.g. triangular arrays, Lindeberg conditions, etc.)